# Find out which PHP-Script starts Apache2-process

Tags: php, apache-2.4, malware

I would like to know how you find out which php-scripts are starting apache2-processes, which are causing high load.

It seems that one user is infected with malware (php-shell). LMD (maldet/maldetect) does not find the file, but there are php-processes that cause a high CPU load from time to time.

Now I would like to know which file started the apache2-process.

With strace I do not get the filename or -path.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can consider auto prepending a script which logs the path/name of each executed php file: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Answer (score 0):

maybe you find some clue with:

```
lsof | grep <PID>
```

(insert the PID of the suspicous process instead of )

This shows you which files/sockets that process has opened.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be seeing the output you want because strace does not follow children/forks by default, try using `strace -f -p $PID -e trace=open,close` to filter `open()` and `close()` calls to any children or threads of that `$PID` (php-shell it sounds like). Here is a handy [strace cheat sheet](http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/11/15/strace-cheat-sheet/) I like to use.